# How to read content of a .MF file using batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder structure as :

```
C:\LDS\some_folder/META_INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

There are many folders with different names in LDS (so i have mentioned it as some_folder) . In each some_folder I have a folder **META_INF** and inside it, I have a file named  `MANIFEST.MF` .

Every `MANIFEST.MF` has content :

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Class-Path: artifact-version:1.0.0

I need to display the folder name , last modified date of `MANIFEST.MF` and artifact-version number of each folder using batch file in WINDOWS .

Comment: `for /r "c:\LDS\ %%i in (META_INF\MANIFEST.MF) do @(<nul set /p "=%%i, %%~ti, " & type %%i|find "artifact-version:"&echo(`

Answer (score 0):

I'd start using `dir /b /s C:\LDS\MANIFEST.MF` from open command line window. this should list all `MANIFEST.MF` files under `C:\LDS` and its subdirectories. Then

```
for /F "delims=" %G in ('dir /b /s C:\LDS\MANIFEST.MF') do @echo %G %~tG
```

should show the same list **with** last modified date. Then

```
for /F "delims=" %G in ('dir /b /s C:\LDS\MANIFEST.MF') do @echo %G %~tG & type "%~fG"
```

should show previous list **and** content of each file. Then

```
for /F "delims=" %G in ('dir /b /s C:\LDS\MANIFEST.MF') do @echo %G %~tG & type "%~fG"|findstr /I "artifact-version"
```

should narrow content of each file of  previous list to lines containing `"artifact-version"` string.

That's my way to solve such kind of question. In a batch script, double the `%` percentage sign in `%G` as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /s C:\LDS\MANIFEST.MF') do (
    echo %%G %%~tG
    type "%%~fG"|findstr /I "artifact-version"
    rem here you could substitute previous `echo … & type …` commands
    rem          with another code snippet to make output more `nice`
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`|` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot JosefZ . This was really helpful . I want to know that right now I am getting the complete path in the output . But I need the output as some_folder    modified_date and artifact version and not the full path

Comment: Fiddle the `echo %%G %%~tG` line with respect to [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) link. Maybe something like  `echo %%~dpG %%~tG`? Pay your attention to [Stephan's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976184/how-to-read-content-of-a-mf-file-using-batch-file/36978710?noredirect=1#comment61512961_36976184) as well.